# When I .... my dinner.I went to bed?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

> When I .... my dinner, I went to bed.

options:

a)had b)have had c)had had

My approach:

I am here unable to use any form of the verb.

Can anyone please explain which form of usage can be used here and why other cannot be used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparent from "*went*", the statement is about *the past*.  The action in the conditional clause (which begins with "*when*") is *simultaneous* with the main clause.  You cannot simultaneously *have* your dinner and *go* to bed, hence the act of having dinner must be *complete* by the time the statement is made.

There are two choices: Past tense and Perfect tense.  Past tense would point to a particular time, and there isn't such in your sentence.  Hence you need the Perfect tense.  Since the entire sentence is in the past, so should be the Perfect tense: Past Perfect:

> When I **had had** my dinner, I went to bed.